# Do you need macroscopic magnitudes like volume for anything else other than convenience in representation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

We know that macroscopic thermodynamic variables can be derived from microscopic physics thanks to statistical mechanics. Even if extremely inconvenient, does that mean we could rewrite all thermodynamic laws using quantum physics variables?

Comment: @ChetMiller Well, we once hired a physics graduate to do an engineering job, and he attempted to do a few analogous things to that  suggestion before we got rid of him. (Trying to calculate the coefficient of thermal expansion of mild steel from its atomic structure, instead of looking it up in a table, was one of the more memorable ones)

Comment: @alephzero Wow.

Comment: @ChetMiller I guess any question always has a witty comment to be made for. Clearly I am not asking about its practical viability but its theoretical correctness, as a conceptual exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, this answer became longer and longer. That is because it much depends on what you consider to be "quantum phsyics variables" and what you consider thermodynamics. In my opinion, there is the standard macroscopic thermodynamics that should not feel any fundamental changes due to installing quantum mechanics at its fundament, while there are also some intersting new kids in town like stochastic thermodynamis. That one deviates from standard thermodynamics, but also has to take extra care for quantum effects at small enough length scales. Here are some musings on both.

---

### Macroscopic Thermodynamics

Let me try to give my view in a short historic summary. Thermodynamics, at its inception, is a theory on the relation between heat and mechanical work and how the two can be transformed. That is Claudius' generation. It turned out that the idea of work can encompass work done by magnetic fields and magnetization or any other conjugate pair, apart from the connection between pressure and volume established in the early days.

Maxwell, Boltzmann, Gibbs and their generation introduced statistical ideas to relate this description to a fundamental theory, which they believed to be Newtonian physics.

Another generation later, Einstein and Planck come along and take statistical ideas to the next level, ultimately leading to the conception of quantum mechanics, and I think in the end Dirac, von Neumann and Landau put quantum statistical mechanics on the same footing as classical statisical mechanics.

Ok, this is history, not physics. Still, I think that while all these developments lead to a richer and more profound understanding of the statistical laws underlying thermodynamics, they did so in order to better justify thermodynamics, not so much replace its well-established laws. At least speaking macroscopically, that is in experiments accessible to the human perception of reality, the correct variables of thermodynamics are still state variables described by the real concave/convex functional relations we know. The whole dilemma of early qunatum mechanics was that no measurement can ever truly observe a superposition, it is just that theories with superpositions of states give the correct predictions.

Maybe an example: Consider something like the Heisenberg ferromagnet. It is clear that this system can not be realized in a classical theory due to the unique algebra of quantum mechanical spins. And indeed, any theoretical approach needs to take this into account. However, the measurements performed on magnetic systems give information in much the same way as one is accustomed to from the theory of gases: We get phase diagrams with their usual features, we can calculate static and dynamic responses by correlation functions and so on. These quantities would still be "classical physics variables" in my understanding. The underlying mechanisms and reasonings are very much quantum mechanical and one needs to work with operators and state densities and all that, and the laws themselves contain different relations - but the proper thermodynamic variables are the same.

That is because the transition from a microscopic description - be it Newtonian or Planckian - requires some form of averaging. This averaging removes the features of the underlying theory (there are no quantum mechanical operators at the level of the fundamental relations in thermodynamics, but neither are there the phase space trajectories nor the symplectic geometry of Hamilton's approach to classical mechanics). If one wanted to go for  a truly deep reason for all that, Ken Wilson's renormalization group theory should be a strong candidate. For example, one can prove that a phase transition depends on symmetries, interaction range and dimensionality of the system. Both classical and quantum theories can provide these properties and they can even coincide in all of them.

Because it was the main antagonist in the question's title: The thing about volume is that it gives you information about the system size, so in a way it is (rather crude) information about the boundary of your system. There is no way of dropping it. The classical ideal gas and a collection of noninteracting quantum particles in a box both need their box to be well-defined. What other truly quantum variable did you imagine should replace volume?

---

### Stochastic Thermodynamics

Now, that was all just talking about macroscopic thermodynamics. A lot of current research is focused on smaller and smaller systems. Over the last 30 years, the field of stochastic thermodynamics emerged, and they try to consider how thermodynamic laws change on length scales of proteins and smaller. A length scale that begins to play a role is the coherence length of a system, that is roughly speaking the minimum size two adjacent subsystems need to have to not feel quantum entangelement or any other weird quantum business from one another. At this scale, you do indeed need fundamental changes to the variables of the system. However, you also need fundamental changes in classical thermodynamics once you are at that scale.

Of course, on this scale volume plays a much less pronounced role. But I think you still need to replace it by providing some information about the way you view the system as a whole, even when you just look at a small subsystem. That way may, however, be quite implicit and hard to track.

I have only dabbled in the field of stochastic thermodynamics, so maybe someone else can give a more insightful overview here. I think my knowledge doesn't extend beyond the wiki article, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_thermodynamics

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically, all non-relatavistic behaviors can *supervene* on quantum mechanics, meaning they can be built up from the first principles of QM.  So in theory, you could do as you say.

However, in practice, such formulations would be utterly useless.  We cannot measure the quantum states of a far off star.  We cannot design a jet engine to atomic precision.  So **all** practical uses of these equations on a macroscopic scale would be tricky.  One would have to define the uncertainties and measurement types that we can achieve using our real physical measurement apparati in the same quantum mechanical language.

When all is said and done, what we would find is that we have to accidentally derive all of the laws you are seeking to avoid having to use.  The macroscopic results would naturally fall out from our ability to measure macroscopic things.  This is the nature of having one set of laws supervene on another.  One set of laws fall out from the other.